# Undefined childNode

Tags: javascript, html, child-nodes

I have some code in html and i want to print the tags using a recursive function. The problem is that childNodes returns one element which is undefined for each li item.

Code.

```js
        var div5 = document.getElementById('div5');

        function printItem(item, paddingLevel) {

            console.log(paddingLevel + item.tagName); 
            paddingLevel += " ...... ";


            var childs = item.childNodes;

            for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                printItem(childs[i], paddingLevel);
            }

        }

        printItem(div5, "");
```

```html
<div id="div5">
      <ul>
           <li>Testing: 0</li>
           <li>Testing: 1</li>
           <li>Testing: 2</li>
           .......
           <li>Testing: 9</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Result in console:

```
DIV
...... UL
......  ...... LI
......  ......  ...... undefined
```

Thank you and have a great day !!!

Comment: `.children` instead of `.childNodes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `childNodes` doesn't filter text nodes which don't have `tagName` property.

use condition to skip those nodes like this:

```
var div5 = document.getElementById('div5');

function printItem(item, paddingLevel) {

    if (item.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        console.log(paddingLevel + item.tagName);
        paddingLevel += " ...... ";


        var childs = item.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            printItem(childs[i], paddingLevel);
        }

    }

}

printItem(div5, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to test the item you're printing, as it may be a [Text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), not an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). You can check that via [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), or just do a check to see if the node has `childNodes`:

```js
var div5 = document.getElementById('div5');

function printItem(item, paddingLevel) {

  if (item.nodeType === 1) { // *** 1 = Element
    console.log(paddingLevel + item.tagName);
    paddingLevel += " ...... ";

    var childs = item.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
      printItem(childs[i], paddingLevel);
    }
  }
}

printItem(div5, "");
```

```html
<div id="div5">
      <ul>
           <li>Testing: 0</li>
           <li>Testing: 1</li>
           <li>Testing: 2</li>
           <li>Testing: 3</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```